# ADDRESS TO RANGE

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula:

=MATCH("*"&"W"&C2&"*",'Raw Data'!$5:$5,0) --> Which extract the column number, then
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,E3,4),"1","") --> I convert to letter
It returns: DH

Finally, I want to use that value of "DH" into the following formula
=INDEX('Raw Data'!A:A,MATCH(E26,'Raw Data'!DH:DH,0))

I tried many times and ways without success.

Data is dynamic, so the first value I'm looking for W2 (for example) will not always be in the same column.

Depending on the variable which you get on the column number, I want the spreadsheet to select that column.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a column letter in `INDEX`? just use the number (result of `MATCH`).

Comment: How? =INDEX('Raw Data'!A:A,MATCH(E26,'Raw Data'! --> I want it inserted here

Comment: Column is the 3rd argument of match. Looks like you want an `=INDEX(range, MATCH(), MATCH())`. Make the `range` in question span all the columns, not just column A, e.g. `'Raw Data'!A:XX`.

Comment: well I'm a bit confused as to what you're setup is, but I'm *guessing* you want something like that.

Comment: I have over 150 columns of data, but depending on a variable, this case W2 (could be W1, W2, W3 or W4) I need to select that specific column.

So after I sort that out, I need to match a number within that same column, starting from row 11 to the last used row (which I already have another formula for that)

But, I still don't know how to merge all that

Comment: Sounds like a nested INDEX/MATCH maybe... a screenshot would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified demonstration of what I *think* you are trying to do here:

[image]

Formula in `A3`:

```
=INDEX(A11:A20,MATCH(A2,INDEX(A11:E20,,MATCH("W"&A1,5:5,0)),0))
```

As you see, this can be done without transformation of a column number into a letter reference. It's simply a matter of nested `INDEX/MATCH` functions as per @BigBen in the comments.

Please adapt the above to suit your ranges.

Few more remarks just for future reference:

- `ADDRESS` - This is a so-called *volatile* function. Though maybe not obvious these type of functions recalculate on any save, open, edit on your worksheet. The more of these, the slower your workbook gets.
- `""&"W"&C2&""` - There is no need to concatenate empty strings in front of other string values leaving you with the exact same results but formulas that are simply harder to read.

Comment: Seems right... I felt like a fool in the comments but it wasn't easy to understand.

Comment: Following OP's formulas and demonstration this is what I got out of it. We'll be fools together if I'm wrong =)

Comment: Thank you both for taking the time the help a stranger. I really appreciate it. It worked like a charm. Sometimes I try to make things more complicated it seems. You both have a terrific weekend!

Comment: @JvdV I forgot to mention that I concatenate that because the original cell contains something like: W2 Total Load +630, Another is: Total Load W3 +680, they're not in the same place, that's why I have to match it anywhere in the cell.
I didn't know about the volatile functions but I'll keep that in mind.